# security and implementation challanges when launching the token

Tags: tokens, security

I would like to know what are security holes when launching an ERC20 token or other tokens. Below is my process of launching token:

- Creates an ERC20 token contract with truffle.
- Defines network configuration of ropsten.infura.io with HD wallet by passing mnemonic of wallet to sign transactions.
- Compile and migrate it to ropsten network.
- Doing transaction(transfer etc) from truffle console / Myetherwallet interface interation / web3 interface etc.

suggestions in order to improve security are highly appreciated.
looking forward Thanks :)